# Send email and activate customer via. Shopify API

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopify

I'm creating a private app for a customer that are using Shopify as the shopping platform.

At the moment, I'm creating the customers via. the Shopify API (http://docs.shopify.com/api/customer).

It's working perfectly, but everytime I'm creating a new customer, it doesn't send an email with the activation link, but I need to do that via. the administration customer section.

Does anyone know if that is possible to do via. the API?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the customer with the attribute  "send_email_invite": true and then Shopify does indeed send the email out with the activation link... been doing that for years and it works.

Comment: Is that also working with private apps?

This is the variable I'm sending with the call: http://pastebin.com/gmwSJfeA (I've replaced the email with some text, just in case some spam bots would find it).

Comment: Private or Public App makes no diff. Assuming it creates the customer fine, but does not send the activation email with the link to activate the account, what state is the account in that you do create? When you download the account by it's newly created ID, what does that record look like?

Comment: When I create the customer, the state is "disabled". But I'm trying to set the state to "enabled" or "invited", but without any change.

The array of the newly created customer looks like this: http://pastebin.com/DWF7ayV0